# uv unwrap crashes/"Unwrap failed to solve 1 of 1 island(s), edge seams may need to be added"

Tags: uv, edges

im new to blender, but im trying to unwrap a head. ive done U> Unwrap and UV> Unwrap, and added a UV map under object data properties and tried the unwrap again. still crashed. at one point, it even crashed my whole computer.

i tried to post my blender file but it was too big so i isolated the head mesh only (no shaders or other meshes). when i tried to unwrap it again, it said "Unwrap failed to solve 1 of 1 island(s), edge seams may need to be added". i added the link to the file below. i have no idea what this means ToT. if u have any suggestions pls be thorough since im still new. any help?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e0NRYv57FxfH7fVAemr2yyVLu3F18Ivt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i am using blender 4.0 btw

Comment: UV edge seams are something you can add on to the edges in your mesh, that tell the UV unwrapper where you want certain parts to be split. You can do so by selecting edge select mode by pressing 2 on your keyboard, then select the edges you want, and right click -> add seam. Try to add it along a loop, perhaps one that will split the head in half usually works well

Comment: Just that head has over 700,000 edges on it so it's not surprising that attempting to UV unwrap it failed! The topology is so complex that it's not even possible to add seams to it and trying Limited Dissolve doesn't really help much either.

Comment: Incidentally, it did unwrap without problems here but the result of a straight unwrap isn't of any use and using Smart UV Project isn't much better to be honest. You need a decent machine to unwrap something that complex anyway and it shouldn't crash on you.

Comment: @john eason ok so what do i do? is there a way to make it have not so many edges? I made it high res so i could have a detailed mesh but this has backfired 

Comment: Only by starting again. As I said, Limited Dissolve doesn't help much with UV unwrapping. Although it reduces the vertex and edge count it does it in such a way that you couldn't mark the seams to allow better UV unwrapping. Trying to use the Decimate Modifier doesn't help either and would probably crash your machine if it crashes UV unwrapping. Why do you need such a high poly mesh anyway?